# PHP mail script html formatting

Tags: php

someone kindly posted this code for me but it only returns
"/table" 
in the resulting email - any ideas? Does it need a closing html tag?

```
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$formcontent ="<table border='1'>";
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
{
$formcontent.="<tr>";
$formcontent .= "<td>$field:</td> <td>$value</td>";
$formcontent.="</tr>";
}
$formcontent .= '<tr><td>User-Agent: </td><td>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'</td>';
$formcontent ="</table>";
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. It's tricky and very easy to screw up. Using PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both of which make it a trivial process.

Comment: Hi Marc - not familiar with Swiftmailer but will google it - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final line is currently:

```
$formcontent ="</table>";
```

It should be:

```
$formcontent .="</table>";
```

Without the dot, it's overwriting the content, rather than concatenating.

Comment: Ah - my ignorance of PHP shining through I'm afraid - thanks very much for your help -

Comment: You're welcome - it's one of those things that's obvious when you know it's there. A fresh pair of eyes helps no end!